# Android - Firebase - Issue with getChildrenCount() method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I'm building an Android App which is using a Firebase Database.

In my code, I'm trying to get the number of Children in a specific path of my Firebase Database. Having defined the reference of the Firebase specific path, I have made a Listener in order to get the DataSnapshot and then to call getChildrenCount().

After that, I want to use this result in a FOR-Loop. However, the code doesn't work.

It appears that it is executed first the FOR-Loop (I realised that because `Log.v("NUM_OF_PRODUCTS",numOfProducts+"")` outputs 0 insteed of 3) and the Listener is executed after, while in the code, listener code comes first and FOR-Loop code next.

Part of my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    selected_cat = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass_selected_cat");
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    fbdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    fbref_products = fbdatabase.getReference("PRODUCTS/SM_0/" + selected_cat);

    //Listener for getting numOfProducts.
    fbref_products.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            numOfProducts = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    //Print numOfProducts before FOR-Loop being executed.
    Log.v("NUM_OF_PRODUCTS",numOfProducts+"");


    //FOR-Loop 
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfProducts; i++) {
        String str = i + "";
        DatabaseReference product_ref = fbref_products.child(str);

        product_ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                String productName = (String) map.get("productName");

                arrayList.add(productName);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //textView.setText("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

My code works fine if instead the variable `numOfProducts`, we had a specific number.

Could anyone help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data from the Firebase Database is loaded asynchronously. By the time you run your `for` loop it hasn't been loaded yet.

It is easiest to see this if you place a few log statements in your code:

```
System.out.println("Before attaching listener");
fbref_products.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("In onDataChange");

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
System.out.println("After attaching listener");
```

When you run this, the output will be:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener
>
> In onDataChange

This is probably not the order that you expected. But it explains perfectly why `numOfProducts` is still 0 when you start the loop: the data simply hasn't been loaded from Firebase yet.

In initial reaction from pretty much every developer is "I don't want this. How do I make it execute in the right order?" This is a natural response, but one that you'll have to suppress to get anywhere when programming against web/cloud APIs. I also recommend reading my answer here: [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

The solution is to reframe your solution from "first I'll get the number of products and then I'll loop over the products" to "whenever I get the products, I'll loop over them".

In code that is:

```
fbref_products.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        numOfProducts = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfProducts; i++) {
            String str = i + "";
            DatabaseReference product_ref = fbref_products.child(str);
    
            product_ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    String productName = (String) map.get("productName");
    
                    arrayList.add(productName);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //textView.setText("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Aside from the whole dealing with asynchronous events, you can significantly simplify this code:

```
fbref_products.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot productSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String productName = productSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
            arrayList.add(productName);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }        
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. this uses only a single listener. Your second listener is not needed, since retrieving a node already retrieves all data *under* that node as well. You can loop over the child nodes.
2. this doesn't first extract a HashMap, but simply reads the data from the child snapshot directly.

One more change you should consider is to keep a separate list of product names. You now retrieve all product data to show a list of names, which is wasteful. If you keep a separate list of just the product names, you can load that instead. You'll find that a common theme when using Firebase (or almost any NoSQL database): model the data in your database the way you show it on the screen.